# Apple Watch notification error "Unhandled Category"

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, ios8-extension, ios8.2

I'm working with Apple Watch Notifications.
I defined my own category "myAppcategory" and passed the same to notification payload.
But, still i'm receiving below warning in XCode.

> Warning: Notification category "(null)" not found. Define this category or a default category in your storyboard.

And result in watch simulator is below

[image]

Can any one help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same issue. For me it was an invalid push notification payload. If you're using a .apns file (for example the sample one provided for notification controllers) to test make sure it's formatted correctly.

Comment: This was my issue, I forgot to add a comma in some extra keys I added to the payload. It defaulted the category name to myCategory (when that was no where mentioned as the category name).

Answer (score 3):

This issue is most probably is caused after a mistaken edit that broke the formatting on the `PushNotificationPayload.apns` file. To resolve this issue fix the formatting in your `.apns` file.

The most problematic part is when you add data to `alert`. Make sure you add comma after each entry, **except last one**.

```
"alert": {
    "body": "Test message",
    "title": "Optional title",
    "name": "MyName"
},
```

Like this.

Comment: Having tested this, I found that a trailing comma didn't cause any problem. Perhaps this is a fix in a recent version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove application from iphone simulator. I had the same error and I've resolved it in this way

Answer (score 0):

Also, watch for the comma in the button list

```
    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
    {
        "title": "Stop/Save Activity",
        "identifier": "stopsave"
    },                                    // <===== THIS ONE HERE
    {
        "title": "Cancel Activity",
        "identifier": "cancel"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add category value in your payload and define it in your storyboard.

```
"aps": {
    "alert": "Test message",
    "sound": "Optional title",
    "category":"myCategory"
}
```

reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html